# Sent a 1079 byte transaction without a fee on accident

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees

Honest mistake, I thought Bitcoin-Qt would ask if I wanted to add the fee which it did not. What are the chances this transaction will make it through? Is there anyway I can cancel this transaction or do I have to just wait it out and see? It was sent from Bitcoin-Qt v0.8.2-beta

Comment: There's no need to cancel it. If you don't want to wait anymore, just submit a new transaction that claims the same outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin-Qt will insist you add a fee if (and only if) it's required to get confirmed *ever* - so it should confirm eventually. If you want to always include a fee for a faster confirmation, go into Settings. Unfortunately, while Bitcoin allows you to add a fee later, Bitcoin-Qt does not support this.

Comment: I was in the impression fees cannot be retroactively added. Is there any material regarding these "fee corrections" I could read?

Comment: Essentially you just double-spend the inputs to the same destination, but include a higher fee.